# Элементарное в циклах while

Tags: python

На начальном этапе изучения питона столкнулся с проблемой понимания циклов while. Вот код.

```
weather = float(input())
summa = 0
while weather > -300:
    summa = summa + weather
else:
    print(summa)
```

В задании требуется вывести финальное значение переменной summa, после прибавления к этой переменной другой переменной weather со значениями больше, чем 300. Проблема в том, что при вводе числа < -300, ничего не происходит. Пытался использовать оператор continue, но к успеху это не привело. Очень буду рад помощи.

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Условия задачи действительно не понятны, но я попробовал решить.

Циклу `while` необходимо условие выхода из цикла или изменяемое значение которое будет менять условие цикла которое по идеи должно привести к выходу из цикла  у вас ни того ни другого нет. У вас если значение `weather` больше чем `-300` цикл попадёт в бесконечное выполнение, иначе просто выводит значение переменной `summa`.

На сколько я понял условие вашей задачи вам необходимо вывести сумму переменных `summa` и `weather` если значение введённые пользователем больше чем `-300`, иначе если значение введенное пользователем меньше или равно `-300` попросить пользователя повторно ввести значение

```
weather = float(input("Введите значение больше чем -300\n"))
summa = 0
while True:
    if weather > -300:
        print(summa, end=" ")
        summa = summa + weather
        print("+",weather,"=",summa)
        break
    else:
        weather = float(input("Попробуйте еще раз\n"))
```

Answer (score 1):

Если вы введёте "числа < -300", то как раз что-то произойдёт - выведется сумма 0.

Иначе программа попадёт в бесконечный цикл - ведь изменяете вы `summa`, а проверяете по-прежнему `weather` с тем же значением, что ввели.

Как исправить? Для этого нужно более чётко поставить условие задачи.