# Объясните элементарнейшие действия с циклом while

Tags: python

На начальном этапе изучения Питона столкнулся с проблемой освоения и понимания цикла while. Представим ситуацию, что мне нужно посчитать сумму всех значений переменных, введенных с клавиатуры. Строго не судите, код написан очень плохо и как я уже сказал, я только изучаю базовые аспекты. Вот мой код.

```
weather = float(input('Введите показатель температуры\n'))
summa = 0
while weather > -300:
    summa += weather
print(summa)
```

Как я это вижу. Пользователь вводит какое-либо число, которое будет удовлетворять условия выполнения цикла. Возьмём число `50`. `50 > -300`. Это значит, что `50` добавляется к переменной `summa` и теперь ее значение стало равным `50`. Происходит второй круг выполнения цикла. Тут я надеюсь, что консоль снова потребует от пользователя ввести число и так должно продолжаться до тех пор, пока пользователь не введёт значение `weather` не будет меньше `-300`. Понимаю, что выглядит как полный абсурд, но совершенно нет осознанного понимания того, как сделать так, чтобы во время выполнения цикла пользователь мог вводить значения до тех пор, пока они не перестанут удовлетворять условие. Может тут как-то должен быть задействован оператор `continue`?

Comment: У вас проблемы не с пониманием цикла, а с пониманием переменных.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Элементарное в циклах while](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1360336/%d0%ad%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%80%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b5-%d0%b2-%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%85-while)

Answer (score 0):

**В данный момент ваш код работает так:**

1. Запрашивает ввод данных в переменную `weather`
2. Объявляется переменная `summa` со значением `0`
3. Действия (в цикле) до тех пор, пока `weather > -300`:

   1. Прибавляем к `summa` значение `weather`

---

Это видно и в вашем коде, но, возможно так будет нагляднее. В вашем цикле выполняется всего одно действие - прибавление значения `weather` к `summa`.

Поскольку запрос ввода данных в консоль был выполнен всего один раз в начале кода, значение `weather`, из вашего примера, всегда будет равно `50` и **цикл никогда не завершится**, так как значения в его условии не меняются.

---

Если вам нужно, чтобы какое-то действие повторялось в цикле, то вам нужно это действие поместить в тело цикла.

```
weather = 0
summa = 0
while weather > -300:
    weather = float(input('Введите показатель температуры\n'))
    summa += weather
print(summa)
```

Таким образом, данный код будет делать все тоже самое, что и у вас, но запрашивать ввод данных на каждой итерации *(каждом шаге)* цикла.

Answer (score 0):

Программа прервется как только пользователь введет число меньше **-300**. Причем в сумму его не запишет

```
summa = 0
while True:
    weather = float(input('Введите показатель температуры\n'))
    if weather < -300:
        break
    summa += weather
print(summa)
```